# JsonConvert DeserializeObject always null

Tags: json, deserialization

```
{"product":{"title":"Test Product 0","id":29,"created_at":"2015-10-22T09:00:24Z", "price":"10:00"}}
```

I receive above result from web api get. Then I try to convert it to my Product type. But it gives null always.

```
Product prod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(result);

public class Product
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `id` is a number, not a string, in the JSON.

Comment: Class is changed like follows. Didn't solve the problem
public class Product
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Allright; I've seen it solve a similar question a day ago or so. To find out if it's the class mapping or the JSON parsing, could you deserialize to the default object first (no `<Product>`) and see if that is null also? Or rather, what is `result`?

Comment: Yes, then it shows values. Then how to convert it to <Product> type?